# Blend CALayers background colors

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, calayer

I'm trying to achieve something similar to this:

[image]

I want to have several layers that blend their color with whatever color is under them. I've been reading a bit about `Core Image Filter` but I don't have images here. I just want to merge layers.

Can someone point me in the right direction to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

A lazy way to do this would be to make each layer partly transparent. That will cause their RGB values to be mixed, along with the color underneath (probably white). I suspect, though, that the bottom-most layer will be mixed in at a smaller percentage than the top layer unless you adjust the opacity of each layer to compensate.

You could indeed use a Core Image filter to combine multiple images with additive coloring, but that's images, not layers, and you'd have to write code to apply the filter. (You can attach Core image filters to layer in Mac OS, but not iOS.)

Answer (score 0):

You just make sure all the layers(circles in your case) are sublayer of a single CALayer which background colour is transparent .
Then apply lighten blending mode.

```
redCircleLayer.compositingFilter = @"lightenBlendMode";
greenCircleLayer.compositingFilter = @"lightenBlendMode";
blueCircleLayer.compositingFilter = @"lightenBlendMode";
```